# TDD: Decouple test code from production code, avoiding one-to-tone correspondence. Explanation and code examples

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I try to understand better under what circumstances one-to-one correspondence between test code and production code is not needed, after reading Uncle Bob's [TDD Harms Architecture](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html). For example, first:

"a one-to-one correspondence implies extremely tight coupling."

then below:

"If you look at part of FitNesse written after 2008 or so, you’ll see that there is a significant drop in the one-to-one correspondence. The tests and code look more like the green design on the right."

It does not explain why the one-to-one correspondence is dropped.

I want to know why, on the assumption that only public method is tested

- Is it because the production class or method are covered by other test class/method INDIRECTLY? or
- Is it because they are so trivial, or the developer is so confident, that the test code is dropped? or
- Are there general design pattern or rules that can help writing code that decouples test from production code?
- Any other reason?

Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because the production class or method are covered by other test class/method INDIRECTLY?

Basically yes. The tests are there to ensure the system has some property. Usually that the system provides some functionality. (We sometimes write test to reproduce a defective behavior, too, however, for instance when filing a bug report.) So if you write new tests that are less fragile because they are more decoupled from the production code, and also more expressive because they state what functionality the system achieves, and not how the system achieves it; the old *direct* tests don't provide any additional value, and should be removed because they are a maintenance burden. Indirection enables you to achieve both decoupling and expressiveness.

> Are there general design pattern or rules that can help writing code that decouples test from production code?

Uncle Bob's green diagram on the right would be and example of the facade pattern because it hides multiple, complicated services behind a single interface.

To clarify one thing for junior developers do not read Uncle Bob's UML diagram literally. Services implement the facade in a loose sense.

See below example to see how application services *implement* the test facade. Also to see the difference/relationship between and the application facade and the test facade (as per @jonrsharpe's comment). A tip can be: write your test facade such that it reads like the stories you will demo, or the scenarios in your test plan etc. :

```
class SomeTestClass
{
    public void users_cant_register_without_providing_contact_info()
    {
        failsWithMissingContactInfoErrorMessage( 
            () -> user.sendsRegistrationFormWithMissingContactInfo());

        admin.doesntSeeInRegisteredUsers(user);
    }

    private failsWithMissingContactInfoErrorMessage(Runnable r)
    {
        failsWithErrorMentioning(r, MissingContactInfo.class, "missing contact");
    }
}

class UserFacade // Can be named after roles
{
    CommandInterface handler;
    ViewInterface view;

    String enteredEmail;
    String enteredPhoneNumber;

    void sendsRegistrationFormWithMissingContactInfo()
    {
        fillsTheForm();
        leavesEmailBlank();
        leavesPhoneNumberBlank();
        sendsRegistrationForm();
    }

    void leavesEmailBlank()
    {
        this.enteredEmail = "";
    }

    void leavesPhoneNumberBlank()
    {
        this.enteredPhoneNumber = "";
    }

    void entersAValidEmail()
    {
        this.enteredEmail = "valid@example.com";
    }

    void entersAValidPhoneNumber()
    {
        this.enteredPhoneNumber = "+1-541-754-3010";
    }

    void entersAnInvalidPhoneNumber()
    {
        this.enteredPhoneNumber = "##123456**";
    }

    void sendsRegistrationForm()
    {
        handler.handle(new RegisterNewUser(enteredEmail, enteredPhoneNumber));
    }

}

class AdminFacade
{
    BackEnd backEnd;

    void doesntSeeInRegisteredUsers(UserFacade user)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code sample, the sendsxtInfo() method is made public, and the four methods within it could be private (ideally, if it is possible), or public, so once the test code calls sendsxtInfo(), it also TESTs all four methods. Is this the none one-to-one correspondence Uncle Bob is talking about. Is it the only reason? That is basics and what we are practising. But I think other methods like the sendxInfo() method that are public have one-to-one correspondence, except that it is called by other methods, which is tested indirectly.

Comment: I don't think this is a facade pattern like used to expose system services, but is a bit similar.

Comment: `users_cant_register_without_providing_contact_info` does not test the methods of the facade. It tests one property of the *Register New User* use case. I have left out access modifiers s.a. public/private because they would be just noise here. UserFacade/AdminFacade etc classes form a test facade so you need not directly work with the application interface. `CommandInterface`, `BackEnd` etc are probably facades themselves. For instance `CommandInterface.handle(RegisterNewUser)` probably delegates to sthg like `RegistirationService.Register(newUser)` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost here. Do you mean UserFacade and AdminFacade are test code, not production code? Another question is that, the users_x_info() method is calling sendxInfo() method in UserFacade class, which is testing UserFacade class. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes `UserFacade` and `AdminFacade` are test code. You would either deliberately introduce them to go to an architecture like Uncle Bob suggests or if your tests matched your scenarios closely and you factored repeating steps in the scenarios out into separate methods you would be 80% there anyways. 

No. All you see is test code. The whole point is that your tests depend only on a few interface names and method signatures `CommandInterface` etc. (the facade of your production code) such that they are not fragile in the face of refactoring of the production code.

Comment: 1 Is it correct that both classes `UserFacade` and `AdminFacade` can be used by other test code apart from `SomeTestClass` class? Questions 2-4 refer to in the green right diagram of Uncle Bob: 2. `xxxFacade` is like the API box? 3. `SomeTestClass` is like User boxes? 4 production is like the Service boxes? 5. Which one is production code in your example?

Comment: 1-4 Yes to all. 5. `CommandInterface` etc. are production code. The production code is not shown, to demonstrate you need not see the details. Decoupling means you need to know as little as possible. because production code is only invoked in the test facade classes, any changes in the production code would not require changes in the test code. Also in such a case, if you've fixed `sendsRegistrationForm()` you will fixed all the test cases that use it directly or indirectly.

Comment: 6. Is class RegisterNewUser production code too? I know better after previous comment, and would like to know more on this. Any links or resource for further reading would be very much appreciated. Thanks for that.

Comment: 6. Yes. `RegisterNewUser` would correspond to a request model in Uncle Bob's clean architecture: [in this diagram](https://goo.gl/images/SZDBYX) `CommandInterface`, `ViewInterface` would correspond to boundary interfaces on the same diagram. The following books go beyond the usual toy cases: [book 1](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/pages/book.html) [book 2](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com).

Comment: I have read Book 1, but I cannot remember this pattern (1-to-1, facade etc). On book 2, it has good ratings. But I doubt there is a C# version that is same good. My profession is C# based (:(). Python version of this book might not 100% apply for C#. Upvoted the links

Comment: You cannot remember this pattern because this probably isn't a named pattern in any book. The books I mention demonstrate acceptance tests, which by definition cannot rely on implementation details. 2nd book also contains how to refactor tests for various goals (including making them more robust). I don't need to imitate what I read elsewhere. To be honest if uncle bob had written something like "If your tests break when you refactor your production code, add a layer of indirection" that would be enough for me too.

Comment: I cannot find a book like Book 2 in C# version. Thanks for all the info. I am marking it the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is hinted on in the article, but not clearly explained.

The core idea here is that code changes. So if you follow ideology that tests should have one-on-one structure to the code it is testing, then if structure of the code changes, so needs structure of tests.

But that is exactly what you don't want. You want to be able to rename methods or extract classes without worrying about tests and have assurance that tests will report if the change didn't break anything. And changing the tests increases risks that those changes would break the tests. Also, having to change the tests along with code needs more time.

In my experience, the best way is to build a wrapper or facade around the tested code. This facade makes the tests more clearly describe intent and makes it easy to make structural changes to the code under test without major changes to the tests themselves. Only change is really needed within the wrapper.

Example that is close to what I have in mind are BDD tests. The wrapper around the code provides the text based API so tests are easier to write and understand, and usually this text-based API doesn't expose the structure of the implementation. But the wrapper doesn't have to go as far as providing BDD-styled text API. It can use simple class-based "domain specific language" that is using the language's features instead of BDD test framework.

Comment: It's not clear from your answer, do you suggest implementing facade exclusively for tests?

Comment: @AlexeyMilogradov Yes, exactly.

Comment: Agree with the first three paragraphs, but why is it better to change the wrapper than the tests? If interacting with the code under test is insufficiently intentful, maybe that's a problem with the code, and hiding it isn't helping. What about the code's other collaborators, would they be clearer if using the wrapper? It sounds like sensible implementation hiding, but *outside* the production code. Do you have any examples?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is better to change SINGLE wrapper than DOZENS of tests. I would say the main idea is that class can be interacted drastically differently when used in production than when used in test. I did have few experiences on my project with this kind of approach, but I just can't, right now, imagine a good, illustrative, example. The real issue for me here is that it really starts making sense if you have complex code with lots of complex tests. Can't really show it on simple example.

Comment: @Euphoric Does your wrapper/facade's public methods still have one-to-one correspondence with test code? Facade is normally a service layer used for external party, which is only part of an app. The rest of an app cannot all use the same wrapper/facade, e.g. domain model, app layer.

Comment: @Pingpong No, the API of the wrapper is different, which is the main point of such wrapper. I'm not sure which design pattern name would fit this kind of "wrapper" best.

Comment: @Euphoric is it like the code that abuzittin gillifirca provides?